# Detect Multiple Intents from Call Center Conversation transcripts

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-classification, multiclass-classification

I am trying to build a Model that can take the User conversation, that involves dialogues, as Input and Find all the Intents involved in it. This is Basically an Intent Detection Problem. However, Normally labeling Sentences and extracting the features out of it and building an Intent classifier wouldn't work here because Multiple Intents might be Available in a Single Conversation. Is there any Tool / Way / any pipeline that I should follow to achieve this Use case.

Comment: Rasa supports this

Comment: Oh cool. Lemme explore and post if there are any more queries. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

here is a list of references on multiple intents detection (some with links to github repos) -

1. GL-GIN: Fast and Accurate Non-Autoregressive Model for Joint Multiple Intent Detection and Slot Filling (2021)

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.01925v1.pdf
- https://github.com/yizhen20133868/GL-GIN

2. Joint Multiple Intent Detection and Slot Labeling for Goal-Oriented Dialog (2019)

- https://aclanthology.org/N19-1055.pdf

3. Towards Open Intent Discovery for Conversational Text (2019)

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.08524.pdf

4. MULTI-CLASS CLASSIFICATION WITHOUT MULTICLASS LABELS (2019)

- https://openreview.net/pdf?id=SJzR2iRcK7
- https://github.com/yizhen20133868/GL-GIN

Comment: of course, an out-of-the-box straight forward approach would be to use a rolling window (e.g. 10-15 tokens, rolled by 5 tokens) and get a prediction for each query/text segment.